# OS X LION: Unable to launch my application UI

Tags: osx-lion

I am developing a Mac application, which is enabled as "Agent", running as a service always in the background, even after reboot as well. I do have an login UI. But, there are default options, "Close" (⤬) and minimize (⎯) and restore (♰) coming in the login UI. So, user can close the app UI. The issue now is, If user closes the app UI by clicking on "Close" (⤬) option (but the app still runs in the background), then how can i launch the UI again? I tried double clicking the .app file, but it is not launching the UI. I think, because the app is already running in the background. I have been trying for solution so many hours, couldn't find it.
Could someone please help me to resolve this problem? If i closed the app UI(though the app runs still in the background), then i need to have an option to launch the UI back again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding a tray icon to your application, this will allow the user to get back to your GUI by clicking on your tray icon. [or clicking on menu from your tray icon]